# Is it possible to verify toast in appium, using selendroid mode?

Tags: selenium, appium, selendroid

Is it possible to verify toast in appium, using selendroid mode?

If it does,
 can someone explain how it's done?

Answer (score 1):

you can do that using the following code:

```
selendroidDriver.findElementById("showToastButton").click(); // Button that shows toast upon clicking
        WebElement toast = TestWaiter.waitForElement(By.linkText("Hello selendroid toast!"), 3, selendroidDriver);
        Assert.assertNotNull(toast);
```